# How to install nginx from source;: Got SSL_OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDING error

Tags: linux, nginx, openssl, debian

When I try to install nginx/rtmp using many tutorials (Debian)  I got

I followed: 
http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/11/streaming-video-demand-nginx-rtmp-module/
and
http://blog.hemp-society.de/2013/08/nginx-rtmp-installation.html

and all got me the same error:

I tried with these 2 configurations:

> ./configure --add-module=/root/nginx/nginx-rtmp-module/
>   --with-http_ssl_module --prefix=/usr/local/nginx-streaming/

```
./configure --add-module=../nginx-rtmp-module-master
```

**~/nginx/nginx-1.4.3# make**

make -f objs/Makefile
make[1]: entrant dans le répertoire « /root/nginx/nginx-1.4.3 »
cc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -g  -I/root/nginx/nginx-rtmp-module/ -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
                -o objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.o \
                src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c: In function ngx_ssl_create:
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:189:5: error: âSSL_OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDINGâ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:189:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[1]: *** [objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.o] Erreur 1
make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /root/nginx/nginx-1.4.3 »
make: *** [build] Erreur 2

It looks like the problem is openssl.

```
 make install
```

make -f objs/Makefile install
make[1]: entrant dans le rÃ©pertoire Â« /root/nginx/nginx-1.4.3 Â»
cc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -g  -I/root/nginx/nginx-rtmp-module/ -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
                -o objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.o \
                src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c: In function ângx_ssl_createâ:
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:189:5: error: âSSL_OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDINGâ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:189:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[1]: *** [objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.o] Erreur 1
make[1]: quittant le rÃ©pertoire Â« /root/nginx/nginx-1.4.3 Â»
make: *** [install] Erreur 2

can someone help me with that ?

Comment: Please add your nginx `configure` command.

Comment: I have added them. Infact I followed the tutorials form links I provided.

Comment: `SSL_OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDING` was removed in OpenSSL 1.0.2. According to Debian's package search, [the distro uses OpenSSL 1.0.1](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libssl), and not higher versions (unless you are using `rc-buggy`). What version of OpenSSL are you using?

Comment: how to deteremine the version of openSSL used ?

Answer (score 1):

> can someone help me with that ?

Do you have `openssl-dev` installed? On Debian and friends, you need to install `libssl-dev`. On Fedora and friends, you need to install `openssl-devel`.

Or are you using OpenSSL located in a non-standard directory?

In both cases you need to configure with `--with-http_ssl_module`.

In case OpenSSL is in a non-standard location, you also need to supply the paths to the OpenSSL headers with `-I` using nginx's `--with-cc-opt`; and the libraries with `-L` and `-l` using nginx's `--with-ld-opt`.

See the project's [Building nginx from Sources](http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html).

---

**Edit**: Also see See OpenSSL Bug 3208: [Planned removal of SSL_OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDING breaks dependent software](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3208&user=guest&pass=guest) if you are using OpenSSL 1.0.2 or higher.

If using OpenSSL 1.0.2 or higher, you might try adding the following in `ngx_event_openssl.c`:

```
#ifndef SSL_OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDING
# define SSL_OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDING 0
#endif
```

In essence, it turns the define into a no-op.

Also see [nginx Bug 462](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/462): [OpenSSL Safari Workaround (SSL_OP_SAFARI_ECDHE_ECDSA_BUG)](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/462). It tries to work around an Apple `SecureTransport` bug.

Comment: libssl-dev is installed.


I was able to install nginx with no problem before. I am not able to do that nowdays any more and tried on 3 Pcs.

Comment: ok: thanks for the info. But this does really helps me about how to install nginx

Comment: Tries this: 
#ifndef SSL_OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDING
# define SSL_OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDING 0
#endif

no changes